# How to delete a specified row from a Powerpoint table using Microsoft Office Interop with C#

Tags: c#, powerpoint

Is it possible to delete any row from a Powerpoint table using office Interop with C#??

```
PowerPoint.Application objApp;
PowerPoint.Presentations objPresSet;
PowerPoint._Presentation objPres;
PowerPoint.Slides objSlides;
PowerPoint._Slide objSlide;
PowerPoint.TextRange objTextRng;
PowerPoint.Table objTable;

objApp = new PowerPoint.Application();

//objApp.Visible = MsoTriState.msoTrue;

objPresSet = objApp.Presentations;
objPres = objPresSet.Open(strTemplate,
MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse);
objSlides = objPres.Slides;
objSlide = objSlides[1];

for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    objTable.Rows.Add(objTable.Rows.Count);
{           

// How to delete any rows ???
```

`

Comment: What framework are you using? Are you developing a VSTO add-in or working with a PPT or PPTX file from vanilla C#?

Comment: I am using VS 2008. And Created the table with some rows using C# and I want to delete last row , but unable to do it .

Comment: Please edit your question to show the code you have, such as how you created the table in the first place. Please do not post your code in a comment reply, there is an "Edit" link below your question for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The Rows collection in PowerPoint is somehow strange, i.e. to delete a row you have to tell the row to delete itself. This means that you have to use the `Delete()` method on a row (you can obtain it as a result from `Add`, or using the `Item[]` property on the Rows collection).

Be careful that Delete raise an exception when you try to delete a row that is the only one in the Table. In these situation you should delete the Table instead.